# Possible bug rendering a number of HTML sup/sub tags

Tags: bug, design, markdown, markdown-rendering

Regarding my answer to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58463578/how-can-i-justify-that-f64from-bits0x3fe9000000000000-u64-0-781250-f64), it appears there may be a rendering bug.

In the third-last paragraph (only two other paragraphs following it in case that's an Australian phrase), I have a series of terms of the form `1/n`.

The actual question text which is meant to render this data is (I've inserted spaces around the numbers just to make it easier to compare line contents):

```
<code><sup>1</sup>/<sub> 4,194,304 </sub></code>,
<code><sup>1</sup>/<sub> 2,078,152 </sub></code>,
<code><sup>1</sup>/<sub> 1,048,576 </sub></code>,
<code><sup>1</sup>/<sub> 524,288   </sub></code>,
<code><sup>1</sup>/<sub> 131,072   </sub></code>,
<code><sup>1</sup>/<sub> 8,192     </sub></code>,
<code><sup>1</sup>/<sub> 4,096     </sub></code>,
<code><sup>1</sup>/<sub> 256       </sub></code>,
<code><sup>1</sup>/<sub> 128       </sub></code>,
<code><sup>1</sup>/<sub> 64        </sub></code>,
<code><sup>1</sup>/<sub> 32        </sub></code>, and
<code><sup>1</sup>/<sub> 8         </sub></code>.
```

Now most of these render okay but the final two appear to have the `1` rendered normally, *not* as a superscript:

[image]

I *thought* this might have to do with the fact that they're on a new line but changing the window size doesn't appear to affect the others:

[image]

That second graphic shows the difference between the sizes of the `1` characters much more clearly by the way.

Those images were taken from Microsoft Edge but I don't think it's a browser issue since Firefox does exactly the same thing.

---

Strangely enough, the exact same sequence renders fine here on Meta:

`1/ 4,194,304`,
`1/2,078,152`,
`1/1,048,576`,
`1/524,288`,
`1/131,072`,
`1/8,192`,
`1/4,096`,
`1/256`,
`1/128`,
`1/64`,
`1/32`, and
`1/8`.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, it appears it was caused by the paragraph preceding that one:

```
The mantissa bits sum, with each bit adding
<code><sup>1</sup>/<sub>2<sup>n<sup></sub></code>
as `n` starts at `1` and increases to the right:
```

I discovered this by the time-tested method of just removing crap until it started working again :-)

Specifically the `<sup>n<sup>` bit which *should* have been `<sup>n</sup>` with a proper closing tag.

When I fix that, the rendering works okay.

Comment: Of course! Two unclosed `sup` tags causing issues as they don’t get closed with  anything but those two last two.

Comment: Ah, good point, @MartijnPieters, that makes sense as to why there were *two* badly rendered ones.